# select->insert->delete into one sql statement: possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 3 tables, T1 T2 and T3.
Each table has the same columns, except for T3 which has one additional "code" column.

My logic is the following:

-I have to search for any rows in T1 which are also contained in T2.

-For each found row I have to move it in T3, this would mean deleting it from T1 and create it into T3, with code 100.

I know that oracle allows for an insert...from select statement, in which case I have this:

```
insert into T3 (100,c1,c2,c3)
select c1,c2,c3 from T1 where exists (select null from T2 where
 c1=T1.c1 and c2=T1.c2 and c3=T1.c3);
```

This solves the select/insert problem, but would it be possible to add a delete from T1 without having to repeat the select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm)

> This statement is a convenient way to combine multiple operations. It
>   lets you avoid multiple INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE DML statements.

**Example**

This example has all 3 DML operation (INSERT,UPDATE and DELETE)

```
MERGE INTO bonuses D
   USING (SELECT employee_id, salary, department_id FROM employees
   WHERE department_id = 80) S
   ON (D.employee_id = S.employee_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.bonus = D.bonus + S.salary*.01
     DELETE WHERE (S.salary > 8000)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.employee_id, D.bonus)
     VALUES (S.employee_id, S.salary*0.1)
     WHERE (S.salary <= 8000);
```

**Answer to OP**

```
MERGE INTO tab3 D
   USING (SELECT col1 FROM tab1 where col1 in(select col1 from tab2)) S
   ON (D.col1 = S.col1)    
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (D.col1,D.code) 
   values(S.COL1,100);
    DELETE tab1 WHERE(col1 in(select col1 from tab2) );
```

I have tested and working fine.

Comment: Mmm...I always used it when I had to perform an "insert or update" on the same table..I have no idea on how to use it in my scenario. Could you please provide an example by using the query I already wrote?

Comment: what is your delete condition ?

Comment: delete from T1 where exists (select null from T2 where
 c1=T1.c1 and c2=T1.c2 and c3=T1.c3); Basically the same select statement of the topic.

Comment: Seems like that, sounds like a workaround to me but...it does the job so who cares!:)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps useful to use cycle:

```
BEGIN
FOR rec IN
(SELECT c1, c2, c3 from T1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM T2 WHERE
  c1 = T1.c1 AND c2 = T1.c2 AND c3 = T1.c3))
  LOOP
INSERT INTO T3 (100, rec.c1, rec.c2, rec.c3);
DELETE FROM T1 WHERE T1.c1 = rec.c1
   and T1.c2 = rec.c2
   AND T1.c3 = rec.c3;
   END LOOP;
END;
```